# How to use tinylog with netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, tinylog

I am trying to use tinylog with netbeans.
I have some questions regarding that:

1. How to configure tinylog using a property file for netbeans maven web application.
2. How to get logs in JSON format.
3. If I have more than one writers configured then How can I log to only a certain writer and skip other writers.

Comment: your configuration is (should) not be dependent on the IDE you use.a simple google search on 'Java Tinylog netbeans' lead me to this: http://www.tinylog.org/configuration

Comment: @Stultuske, At tinylog site they have mentioned that configuration file should be kept in src directory, but it didn't work for me. As of now I am configuring tinylog using hardcoded file path.

Comment: In case of maven project (regardless of the IDE), you should put `tinylog.properties` file into `src/main/resources` folder. See [Maven project structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) - non-java code, such as a property file, is called a resource in maven terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the first question:

In case of maven project (regardless of the IDE), you should put `tinylog.properties` file into `src/main/resources` folder. See [Maven project structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) - non-java code, such as a property file, is called a resource in maven terminology.

Comment: BTW, you should split your question into 3 separate quesions so that it is easier to answer them.