# How to use or where to place TinyLog properties file with Maven InteliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, tinylog

According to [the TinyLog website](https://tinylog.org/v1/configuration#file)

> The properties file should be named "tinylog.properties" and placed in
> the default package. In common IDEs like Eclipse and Netbeans, it is
> sufficient to put "tinylog.properties" into the "src/" folder or for
> Maven based projects into "src/main/resources".

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561133/how-to-use-tinylog-with-netbeans) also suggests this should be the location of the properties file.

The TinyLog website also shows the following as an example to use in the properties file:

> tinylog.level = warning

The path of my properties file is src/main/resources/tinylog.properties. The content is:

```
tinylog.level = warning
```

However, trace and info prints continue to be created, and `isTraceEnabled()` still returns `true`.

I assume the location of my properties file is wrong, but as far as I can tell it is in the correct location.

Comment: Do you use tinylog 1 or 2?

Comment: @Martin Maven version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for your problem is that you are using tinylog 2 with configuration syntax of legacy tinylog 1. You can find the configuration documentation for tinylog 2 here: https://tinylog.org/v2/configuration/

In your case, the tinylog 2 configuration syntax for `tinylog.properties` will be:

```
level = warn
```